# ContourPlot not working

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions, function-construction, graphs-and-networks

Im trying to use ContourPlot to plot this function, but it's just giving me a blank graph. What's wrong?

My input:

```
ContourPlot[(3 (-2)^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 xy + 5 (-2) (x + y) - 
   2 (-2)^2 == 0, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}]
```

Comment: You have to be careful when multiplying two variables. You have to either put a multiplication symbol (`*`) between them, or a space. So, change `xy` to either `x*y` or `x y`.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Edited * sign and add PlotRange. Hope what you want!

```
ContourPlot[(3 (-2)^2 - 1) (x^2 + y^2) - 2 x*y + 5 (-2) (x + y) - 
   2 (-2)^2 == 0, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]